# Sharepoint CAML query is returing 0 records

Tags: 2010, list-view, query, records-center

I am trying to retrieve the document from the sharepoint by setting the GUID and _UIVersionString has the criteria for the query. It is not retrieving the record from the library.

This is my query :

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString">
                </FieldRef>
                <Value Type="Text">1.0</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="GUID"></FieldRef>
                <Value Type="Guid">{810628DE-065A-4DE4-90A3-126D985009BF}</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

But when I tried with the other library in the same sharepoint with the same query it is getting retrieved in the result.

May i know what might be the problem?

I am using sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

To use greater than or equal to there is a seperate tag in CAML query . Try the below code

```
<Query><Where><And>
<Geq><FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">1.0</Value></Geq>
<Geq><FieldRef Name="GUID"></FieldRef><Value Type="Guid">{810628DE-065A-4DE4-90A3-126D985009BF}</Value></Geq>
</And></Where></Query>
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588239(v=office.11).aspx